# Continuous function on specific topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Hello I am currently learning general topology by myself and I have a question below:

Let $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and its topology $\mathcal{O} =\{\emptyset, X, \{a\},\{b\},
\{a,b\},\{b,c,d\}\}$

Let $f:X \rightarrow X$ be $f(a)=b, f(b)=d, f(c)=b, f(d)=c$

1. Is $f$ continuous at $a$?
2. Is $f$ continuous at $b$?

I am not quite sure how to handle this question.

I would be appreciated if someone could explain me the answer and how to think this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a function been continuous at a point in a general topological space? Did you try to use that definition?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how this is a general topology question, I will assume that the definition of continuity at a point that you've seen is as follows.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Then a map $f:X \to Y$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if for every open neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ in $Y$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

So hopefully with this definition, you know what to check!

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at $a$ because there exists neighborhood $\{a, b\}$ of $b$ of which $f$ has no pre-image of $a$. $f$ is continuous at $b$ because the neighborhood of $d$ is $\{b, c, d\}$ and preimage of $\{b,c,d\}$ is $\{b,c,d\}$. Is this right?

Comment: Not quite. It's somewhat unintuitive, but perhaps you shouldn't think about the usual general definition of continuous in topology (preimage of open set is open) when talking about continuity at a point. I think it's far more intuitive to think about the parallels of the definition I've written and what it means to be continuous in metric spaces. The latter is pretty much asking "for any open ball centred at $f(x)$, can you find a small open ball containing $x$ so that the image of this open ball is contained in the other"?

Comment: In your problem for example, you want to check that if I give you an open neighbourhood $V$ of $f(a) = b$ in $X$, can you find an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $X$ for which $f(U)$ sits inside $V$? I think you'll see that you can...

Comment: Open neighborhood V of $f(a)=b$ are $\{b\}$, $\{a,b\}$, $\{b,c,d\}$. For $\{b\}$ there exists $\{a\}$ such that $f(a)=b$. For $\{b,c,d\}$ there exists $\{b,c,d\}$  such that $f(b)=d, f(c)=b, f(d)=c$. However I don't find such U where $V = \{a,b\}$, $f(U) \subset V$

Comment: Consider the open neighbourhood $U=\{a\}$ of $a$ in $X$.

Comment: Yes. I consider the open neighborhood $U=\{a\}$ of $a$ in $X$. But all I can tell is $f(a)=b$, this does not say anything about such $U$ of $V=\{a,b\}$ with $f(U) \subset V$

Comment: I am unsure of how you missed something this obvious at this point, but it looks like it needs to be spelled completely out for you. We have $f(\{a\}) = \{b\} \subset \{a, b\}$.